# How to Group By Json object in Javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json object which has a zip entries. In the below json object there is zip entries under "Zipcode" key, basically I want to group it by Zip code to show which zip code belongs to what all zone Ids.

for example -  zipcode 7 belongs to  zoneIds 12005,12008,12006,12009 and zipcode 12 belongs to zoneIds 12004,11001. ultimate goal is to show this in some error message.

```
var Json = [{
City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12008,
ZoneName: "test_TP41"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12005,
ZoneName: "test_TP4"
},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12007,
ZoneName: "test_TP456"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12006,
ZoneName: "test_TP5"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12009,
ZoneName: "testgrp16"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 12004,
ZoneName: "test_TP2"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 11001,
ZoneName: "test 20201"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to get a structure like this,

```
obj = {
  ZipCode: [all the objects with this ZipCode],
}
```

```js
Json = [{
City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12008,
ZoneName: "test_TP41"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12005,
ZoneName: "test_TP4"
},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12007,
ZoneName: "test_TP456"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12006,
ZoneName: "test_TP5"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12009,
ZoneName: "testgrp16"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 12004,
ZoneName: "test_TP2"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 11001,
ZoneName: "test 20201"
}]

const res = Json.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.ZipCode)) {
    acc[curr.ZipCode].push(curr);
  } else {
    acc[curr.ZipCode] = [curr];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

If you want you can insert only the ZoneID in the array by doing this,

```
acc[curr.ZipCode] = [curr.ZoneID];
```

and

```
acc[curr.ZipCode].push(curr.ZoneID);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but now how to fetch the information of a particular zip say 7 from the newly constructed object ?

Comment: obj[ZipCode] would be enough, you will find all the zone in an array.

Answer (score 0):

you may follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)  for further more classification

Using ES5+ ,

```
var grouped = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(Json , 'ZipCode'),
                          singleObject=> singleObject.map(item=> _.omit(Json , 'ZipCode')));

console.log(grouped);
```

Hope this would help you

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and create an object with ZipCode as key and ZoneID as value

```js
const Json = [{
City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12008,
ZoneName: "test_TP41"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12005,
ZoneName: "test_TP4"
},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12007,
ZoneName: "test_TP456"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12006,
ZoneName: "test_TP5"},
{City: "ABC",
ZipCode: "7",
ZoneID: 12009,
ZoneName: "testgrp16"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 12004,
ZoneName: "test_TP2"},
{City: "CDE",
ZipCode: "12",
ZoneID: 11001,
ZoneName: "test 20201"
}];

const ZipMappedObj = {}

Json.forEach((k)=>{
if(ZipMappedObj[k.ZipCode]){
  ZipMappedObj[k.ZipCode].push(k.ZoneID)
} else {
ZipMappedObj[k.ZipCode] = [k.ZoneID]
}
})
console.log(ZipMappedObj)
```